# How do you finalize a docker container such that it passes args directly to an executable?

Tags: docker

For example, I have an executable cli that I want to run when I type `docker run -t foo` called `foo-cli`:

```
docker run -it foo "bash"
$: foo-cli --help
yay it works
```

And:

```
docker run -t foo "foo-cli" "--help"
yay it works
```

How do I set docker up so that I can write:

```
docker run -t foo "--help"
```

And have it output:

```
yay it works
```

???

I have tried a variety of commands such as:

```
CMD ["bash", "foo-cli"]
$: docker run -t foo "--help"
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "--help": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply specify the executable as the entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["foo-cli"]
```

you don't need to specify a default cmd, since as you mentioned that will be passed at container run time.

Comment: swear I tried that... when you don't know ¯\_(ツ)_/¯